# IDA 6.8 undo action

Tags: windows, ida

I'm using the `IDA pro v6.8` dissembler. Is there an option to *undo* the last action (e.g. `patching`). In the
`IDA Pro v7.5` the *undo* is bidden to *CTRL+Z* but when i use this combination in `IDA v6.8` just nothing happens. For some reason i have to use the *6.8*, not *7.5* version.
If there is no such an opinion in v6.8 maybe there is some plugin for that?